# Pixelated video while in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, video, vlc

When I play some video using VLC or default Ubuntu 18.04 video player, the video seems pixelated. Screenshots from [Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oS5UD.png) and [VLC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgG1q.png).

I create a simple .HTML file that load the video using the video element and the video seems perfect: [Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Djp77.png).

When using ubuntu default player, the video seems to "lag", but is fine because I use VLC as default for playing videos.

PS: My graphic card is a AMD RADEON RX 570 4GB GDDR5.

Comment: Your links are all the same image and do not seem to be related to your question. Is this intentional?

Comment: @Nmath, please check the images carefully. The "Browser" images seems more "focused" then the others. Pay attention to the bird at left on all images

Comment: What kind of video files are these?  Most video file types use some kind of compression. This is likely a difference in how the application decompresses the file during playback.

Comment: It's a .MP4 video file. If it is a app decompress problem for both VLC and Video, I can do nothing to fix it?

Comment: `.mp4` files are compressed.  There's nothing to "fix" unless you are the content creator.  Taking a screenshot of a single frame is always going to produce those effects, especially with text and computer generated graphics where there is a fine line between two different colors.  Honestly, I don't understand why this is a problem: it's barely noticable.  FYI: the "browser" one doesn't look any better - it's still fuzzy, and you can still see the compression, just in a different way.